# iOS: add char to string while user is tapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

In my `Swift 4` application, I want, in a `textField` to add a special character at the same time that the user tap the second char in the textField.

This is what I did:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.specialTextField {
            if textField.text?.count == 2 {
                self.specialTextField.text! += "|"
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

The problem is that the "|" is not added directly when I write the second char but at the same time as the third one.

For example: I will write "abcd".

While I'm tapping "ab" nothing happened. It's just when I tap the "c" that I get "ab|c".

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a target to your `UITextField` for `UIControlEvent.editingChanged` events to accomplish what you want:

```
specialTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
```

and implement the editingChanged selector method:

```
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // check the contents of your textField and insert the special characters as needed
    print(textField.text!)
}
```

Comment: I believe your `editingChanged` method should be like this:
`@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
  if textField == self.specialTextField {
            if textField.text?.count == 2 {
                self.specialTextField.text! += "|"
            }
        }
}`

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez no need to check which textfield is calling that method considering that there is only one field calling it

Comment: @LeoDabus how can I allow the delete of the "|"? because it's blocked with the `editingChanged`. I mean when the user want to delete the value in the field

Comment: You can subclass UITextField and implement deleteBackward method

Comment: Hi @LeoDabus, can you please help me to solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889183/ios-captured-image-not-cropped-correctly